# How to get runtimepermission in Android 6.0

Tags: android, youtube

I am using the method `YouTubeIntents.createUploadIntent` and getting the exception below,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>   Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.honeycomb.Shell$UploadActivity}:
>    java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10075 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://media/external/video/media/7757

this exception means youtube application does not have permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE。`

How to handle this exception?

Comment: This is how you add runtime  permissons https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html .In your case you need to add "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" on runtime .

Comment: myApplication get permission, but youtube has not get permission; by setting->application->permission->...;just like this set on device give youtube application permission; is any other way?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do this.

```
 if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
    }

    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
    // app-defined int constant

    return;
}
```

Sniplet found here: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how you request permission runtime

first of all add the permission in manifest. then in your activity

```
private static final int REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = SOME_UNIQUE_INT_VALUE;
```

in activity `onCreate` or `onResume` check if permission is already granted else ask for permission to user

```
    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        System.out.println("Permission not granted");

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
           //you should show some sort of information, 
           //show some alert dialog regarding information 
           //to the permission and in ok click call makeRequest()
        } else {
            //passively mnake request, no need to show information
            makeRequest();
        }
    }
```

and this is the actual request making:

```
private void makeRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
```

and receive the request result like this:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {

            if (grantResults.length == 0
                    || grantResults[0] !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                System.out.println("Permission denied");

            } else {

                System.out.println("Permission granted");

            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```